# Lightswitch DesignTimeSafeException

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I hope someone here can help me with this exception. I get this errorbox when I try to publish my "program" created in Lightswitch.
The debugger, doesn't "find" any error in the program, the program works(when started in Visual Studio).

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Lightswitch.DesignTimeHosting.DesignTimeSafeException' occurred.
```

**Additional information**: Unable to load on or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderException property for more information."

Sadly I don't find any satisfying answer. Does anyone know, how to fix this error or at least some ideas where it could come from?

Comment: Have you read any of the "novels" i've posted in SO over the past two weeks regarding local/remote IIS publishing? :)

Comment: Iam reading it right now. Iam kinda new to Developing in Visual Studio Lightswitch and watched the video guids by Beth Massi. Is there a more detailed guide about publishing in LightSwitch? I cant even start the Publish-Wizard, when i click publish the error occures.

Comment: Sounds like missing dependencies or a corrupt install.  Have you tried repairing the Visual Studio install?

Comment: ok, I used the "repair function" sadly still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: I reinstalled Visual Studio then manually searched for updates via google and reinstalled the Update Nr.4 .
After that it worked.

Greetings

Declade